# terminal - all files that have not been edited today

Tags: terminal

I edit a bunch of txt files with the line

```
vim *.txt
```

but what I'd really like to do is edit all the files that haven't been modified in the last day (or n days, or n hours) - what's the most command-line-fu way of doing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
vim $(find * -type f -mtime 0)
```

`$()` is a command substitution. Allows for some magic to be done (in this case, providing a list of files for you to edit). [You can read more about them here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html#3.4.5)

Inside the command substitution we're going to do a `find` command that looks for anything in the current directory (`*`) that is a `file` (`-type f`) and was modified today (`mtime 0`).

`mtime` looks for files that were modified in `n*24`. So if `mtime` was equal to `1`, if would look for files modified yesterday. You could also use `mmin` to look for files that were modified `n` minutes ago.

```
vim $(find * -type f -mmin $[n * 1])
```

In this case, replace n with minute. You could even go and swap whatever you want in that `arithmetic expansion` to suit your needs.

Comment: +1 only cause @slhch changed $() notation instead of superseded backticks :P
Why it is so important?

Comment: @confiq It's not that important but 1) easier to read 2) harder to make nesting errors 3) considered standard now

Comment: Absolutely great answer that solved my problem - just some minor feedback - vim $(find *.txt -type f '!' -mtime 0) was what actually solved the problem (because I wanted txt files only and there was a 'not' in the question) but I'm putting this in only for completeness. Thanks again...